# Error when update AWS Java Lambda Function using Bitbucket Pipelines - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a basic **AWS Lambda** Java Function *my-function*

```java
public class Hello implements RequestHandler<Request, Response> {
    public Response handleRequest(Request request, Context context) {
        String greetingString = String.format("Hello %s", request.name);
        return new Response(greetingString);
    }
}
```

That Lambda function is registered in **AWS** well, the controller is `com.tds.Hello` and is related to **AWS API Gateway** correctly.

The final **JAR** is built through Maven without a problem. When I upload the JAR directly in **AWS** the function works well.

The problem is when I use [Bitbucket Pipelines](https://bitbucket.org/blog/practice-devops-with-custom-pipes-reusing-ci-cd-logic) in order to do an automatic upload (and update) after committing code, the pipeline runs well with **success** status following [This tutorial (Automating AWS Lambda deployments)](https://bitbucket.org/blog/automating-aws-lambda-deployments) but when I test/run the function in AWS I get the following error:

> {"errorMessage":"Class not found: com.tds.Hello","errorType":"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException"}

Does anyone has faced this issue?

Comment: How do you build your JAR file using Maven in Bitbucket Pipelines? It sounds that this process is wrong or you are referencing a wrong artifact file within Bitbucket Pipelines..

Comment: I built the JAR in local, then push it to bitbucket, so the pipeline log shows correctly the result when the zip is created and uploaded, let me try building the JAR inside pipelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was when **ZIP file** was created and passed through **Bitbucket Artifacts**. I avoid to compress (ZIP) file, instead, I used the JAR directly to upload in AWS. I updated `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` as follow:

Old `bitbucket-pipeline.yml`

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Build and package
        script:
          - apt-get update && apt-get install -y zip
          - zip my-function.zip target/my-function.jar 
          - pipe: atlassian/aws-lambda-deploy:0.3.0
            variables:
              AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
              AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
              AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_REGION
              FUNCTION_NAME: 'my-function'
              COMMAND: 'update'
              ZIP_FILE: 'my-function.zip'
```

New `bitbucket-pipeline.yml`

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Build and package
        script:
          - pipe: atlassian/aws-lambda-deploy:0.5.0
            variables:
              AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
              AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
              AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_REGION
              FUNCTION_NAME: 'my-function'
              COMMAND: 'update'
              ZIP_FILE: 'target/my-function.jar'
```

Comment: are you sure that this works with the property `ZIP_FILE ` pointing to a `.jar` file? 
Trying this right now and I always get `ZIP_FILE not exists`